# How to I center vertically in this code (buisness card)?

Tags: latex

How do I vertically center the (web, email, email, mobile) field right to the QR-code?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\setstocksize{55mm}{85mm} % UK Stock size
\setpagecc{55mm}{85mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{45mm}{75mm}{*}
\setulmargins{5mm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{5mm}{*}{*}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setheadfoot{0.1pt}{0.1pt}
\setheaderspaces{1pt}{*}{*}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Spacing}{0.75}%
    \noindent
    \textbf{Helena Doe}\\
    \tiny subtitle \hfill {\color{gray}Division / Employer}\\ 
    \rule{74mm}{.3mm}\\
    \begin{minipage}[t]{33mm}
        \vspace{-0mm}%
        \begin{pspicture}(25mm,25mm)
            % The MECARD format is used to exchange contact information. More information at:
            % http://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/service/imode/make/content/barcode/function/application/addressbook/index.html
\psbarcode{MECARD:N:Last name, First Name;URL:https://fqdn;EMAIL:helena@univ.edu;NOTE:GPG: ;;}{eclevel=L width=1 height=1}{qrcode}

        \end{pspicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{1mm}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{42mm}
        \vspace{-0mm}%
        \begin{flushleft}
        {\scriptsize
            \begin{Spacing}{1}%
            % \textbf{Job Title}\\
            % \hspace{5mm}Speciality 1\\
            % \hspace{5mm}Speciality 2\\
            % \hspace{5mm}Speciality 3 \vspace{2mm}\\
            \end{Spacing}
        }
        {\tiny
            \begin{tabular}{rl}
                {\color{gray}web} & https://fqdn/\\
                {\color{gray}email} & helena@univ.edu\\
                {\color{gray}email} & hxr42@gmail.com\\
                {\color{gray}mobile} & +1 123 456 7890\\
            \end{tabular}
            \vspace*{2mm}
        }
        \end{flushleft}
    \end{minipage}
    \rule{74mm}{0mm}\\
    \texttt{\fontsize{2.84mm}{3.55mm}\selectfont 425B 030A B8D2 0316 CA1B 4709 CA83 5DDA EC31 CA56} % GPG KEY ID
    \end{Spacing}
\end{document}
```

I tried

```
\vapce*{\fill}
```

but this does not work. And I tried some other things, which failed all.

Has anybody an idea?

For compelation I u xelatex!

Okay, I need some more details, sorry, but I have said everything about this problem, this is really annoying. 
complexinfinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`minipage` allows to specify the height with an optional argument. If this option is set, the text can be centred with the `c` key:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\setstocksize{55mm}{85mm} % UK Stock size
\setpagecc{55mm}{85mm}{*}
\settypeblocksize{45mm}{75mm}{*}
\setulmargins{5mm}{*}{*}
\setlrmargins{5mm}{*}{*}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\setheadfoot{0.1pt}{0.1pt}
\setheaderspaces{1pt}{*}{*}
\usepackage{fontspec}


\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]

\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf,pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Spacing}{0.75}%
    \noindent
    \textbf{Helena Doe}\\
    \tiny subtitle \hfill {\color{gray}Division / Employer}\\ 
    \rule{74mm}{.3mm}\\
    \begin{minipage}[t]{33mm}
        \vspace{-0mm}%
        \begin{pspicture}(25mm,25mm)
            % The MECARD format is used to exchange contact information. More information at:
            % http://www.nttdocomo.co.jp/english/service/imode/make/content/barcode/function/application/addressbook/index.html
\psbarcode{MECARD:N:Last name, First Name;URL:https://fqdn;EMAIL:helena@univ.edu;NOTE:GPG: ;;}{eclevel=L width=1 height=1}{qrcode}

        \end{pspicture}
    \end{minipage}
    \hspace{1mm}
    \begin{minipage}[t][24mm][c]{42mm}
       \tiny
            \begin{tabular}{rl}
                {\color{gray}web} & https://fqdn/\\
                {\color{gray}email} & helena@univ.edu\\
                {\color{gray}email} & hxr42@gmail.com\\
                {\color{gray}mobile} & +1 123 456 7890\\
            \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}
    \rule{74mm}{0mm}\\
    \texttt{\fontsize{2.84mm}{3.55mm}\selectfont 425B 030A B8D2 0316 CA1B 4709 CA83 5DDA EC31 CA56} % GPG KEY ID
    \end{Spacing}
\end{document}
```

[image]